# wrong class_name selected by ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many

Hay fellow developer,

When I invoke *@chapter.articles*, rails yields the following error:

```
uninitialized constant Sommaire::Chapter::Article
```

Event if I specify *:class_name => "Sommaire::Article"*,
it yields:

```
uninitialized constant Sommaire::Chapter::Sommaire::Article
```

Since I'm relatively new to rails (3.0.0), this has lost me !

Thanks in advance for your help.
JD

*Below the code from the classes*
in **sommaire.rb**

```
class Sommaire < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :chapters
end
```

in **sommaire/chapter.rb**

```
class Sommaire::Chapter < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ItemBase

  def self.table_name
    'sommaire_chapters'
  end

  belongs_to :sommaire
  has_many :articles, :class_name => "Sommaire::Article"
  validates_presence_of :title, :description

end
```

in **sommaire/article.rb**

```
class Sommaire::Article < ActiveRecord::Base

  include ItemBase

  def self.table_name
    'sommaire_articles'
  end

  belongs_to :chapter

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be worth trying `class_name => '::Sommaire::Article'` (note preceding `::`) to indicate that the Sommaire path is from the root namespace.

It is possible though that there is some conflict between having a `Sommaire` namespace and a `Sommaire` model in which case you may want to rename one or the other.

Comment: Once again the wisdom of the mighty elders has enlighten me.
(I will also think about renaming the "Sommaire" pseudo namespace)